# Error when uploading file with OpenMeetings' importFile REST method

Tags: rest, openmeetings

I installed 3.0.3 OpenMeetings to test access via REST interface, everything worked ok for the methods in UserService and RoomService. But, when I try to upload a pdf file by ImportFile method (FileService), OpenMeetings returns an object FileImportError stating that the file is damaged, and that this may have occurred during the file transfer via http.

When I try to import the same file using the flex application of OpenMeetings everything works right. I'm using Ruby to call the method of ImportFile OpenMeeting, and to test whether my application is wrong, I called the method using Firefox and got the same error.

I am using the following method call (sample only, not the real ruby code):

ImportFile (SID externalUserId, externalFileId, externalType, room_id, isOwner, path,
parentFolderId, fileSystemName)

```
SID = one string with the ID of the session
externalUserId = 'extuser' (string)
externalType = 'exttype' (string)
room_id = 2 (existing room in OpenMeetings)
isOwner = false
path = 'http://10.1.1.25/default.pdf' (The path to the file on an Apache server)
parentFolderId = 0
fileSystemName = 'default.pdf'
```

Also used Eclipse in remote debug to see what was happening and realized that the problem occurs in the conversion of the received file.

I would appreciate some help to solve the problem.

Thanks,

Fernando